# DataTables Server-side Processing - How to add calculated column values not from database?

Tags: php, datatables, server-side

I am following example at
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

In the example code, columns data is return from database like below code

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 )
    );
```

I need to add a 4th column rating and the value is not from database but calculated in a php function. How can I do that?

array( 'db' => 'rating',   'dt' => 3 ) // need get value from php function

Below is the server side php code in the example,

```
$table = 'datatables_demo';
 
// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';
 
// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'office',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'start_date',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'salary',
        'dt'        => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '$'.number_format($d);
        }
    )
);
 
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);
 
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
 
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Comment: Add to the array after you get the sql results as an array, using foreach function

Comment: @Undry How? The data output is generated in SSP::simple function.

Comment: Please read more about MySQL, usually the result is the associative array, that you can browse using foreach function, with the same function you can add new field to the resulting array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer at

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/49799/datatable-ssp-class-php

Need to make changes to function data_output in ssp.class.php

```
static function data_output ( $columns, $data )
    {
        $out = array();
 
        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
        $row = array();
            $params = array();
            for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {
        $column = $columns[$j];
 
                // Is there a formatter?
        if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {
                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i][ $column['db'] ], $data[$i] );
                }
 
        // Do we need to compute?
                elseif (isset( $column['compute'] ) ) {
                    $params[ $column['dt'] ]['compute'] = $column['compute'];
                    $params[ $column['dt'] ]['params'][] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];
                }
 
                else {
                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];
                }
 
            }
 
            if ( !empty( $params ) ) {
 
                foreach ( $params as $dt => $parameters) {
                    $parameterStr = "";
                    foreach ( $parameters['params'] as $p) {
                        $parameterStr .= "$p,";
                    }
                    $parameterStr = rtrim($parameterStr,",");
                    $row[ $dt ] = self::$parameters['compute']($parameterStr);
                }
            }
            ksort($row);
            $out[] = $row;
        }
 
        return $out;
    }
 
    static function shippingMethod($parameterString) {
        $output = "";
        $parameters = explode(",",$parameterString);
        foreach($parameters as $p)
            $output .= "(".$p .")";
        return $output;
    }
 
    static function konka($parameterString) {
        $output = "";
        $parameters = explode(",",$parameterString);
        foreach($parameters as $p)
            $output .= "***".$p ."***";
        return $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try
`$columns[] = [ 'db' => 'rating', 'dt' => 3];`

```
<?php

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 )
    );

$columns[] = [ 'db' => 'rating', 'dt' => 3 ];

print_r($columns);
```

Comment: Hi, this only add to column definition indicates to get data from a database field. I need a definition or a way for this particular column to get data from php function.

Comment: its the same, you just calculate your required data and append the calculated data to the original array as the code I provide